# Getting Direct Image Links from Imgur when given the link of an album

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, imgur

I've been tasked with downloading images from imgur given an image link. Unfortunately these links will be submitted by users and will likely not be direct images (i.imgur.com/xxxx.jpg), and will most often be album links with (hopefully) just one picture.

How would I go about obtaining the direct image link from an album link?

Comment: You might have to download the web page from the album link and find out the URLs of the images on the album webpage and iterate through each URL to download them.

Also, will these links be only from imgur? If yes, then I suggest you take a look at their API

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply, downloading the source might be the easiest way looking at it now, it seems like the link is always the first i.imgur link in the source.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at their API: https://api.imgur.com/

and the official python library: https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython, where there are plenty of useful functions such as `get_album_images(album_id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from imgurpython import ImgurClient

client_id = 'your_id'
client_secret = 'your_secret'

client = ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret)


# get album images as list
def get_images(album_id):

alist = []

items = client.get_album_images(album_id)
for item in items:
    alist.append(item.link)

return alist
```

Worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you take a look at their API [here](https://apidocs.imgur.com/) and the official python [library](https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython), where there are plenty of useful functions such as `get_album_images(album_id)`.
Also, please go through the documentation and [examples](https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md) to understand how to use this library.