# How to take image from imgur image url and the bot send it to channel by python

Tags: python, discord

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
from imgurpython import ImgurClient
import random as r
imgur = ImgurClient("my_client_id", "my_secret_client_id")

@client.tree.command(name="random", description="random image from imgur")
@app_commands.describe(search="name of image")
async def random(interaction: discord.Interaction, search: str):
        rand = r.randint(0, 29)
        items = imgur.gallery_search(q=search, advanced=None, sort='viral', window='all', page=0)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Here is the image", color=discord.Color.random())
        embed.set_image(url=items[rand].link)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

The bot keeps sending the imgur URL containing words and image. So it always return me this
[image: i]-Can anyone help me.Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you also paste the `link` here too.

Comment: when I random image with `ocean` it give me `https://imgur.com/a/WiNq2Hj`

Comment: Yes but that links contains multiple images. An image link should be like this; https://i.imgur.com/Oj4sEz4.jpeg

Comment: Yes that my question about how to make bot get that link not multiple images link

Comment: As I don't have credentials for Imgur, could you try printing `items`? Also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819329/8658598 this answer shows us how to extract images from an album. I'm not sure what `gallery_search` returns, so...

Comment: `gallery_search` as I know is use my search and find image with that search and return the URL to it =

Comment: I doubt that. `gallery_search` would return a link to the gallery, not images themselves. You are selecting a random gallery, not a random image in a gallery. Could you include the results of `print(items)`, `print(items[rand])`?